# How do I update the element inside the arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

```
public class billing{
                private int id;
                //File f=new File("C:/Users/Bingus/Documents/Projects/accounts.txt");
                private String bc;
                private String bd;
                private String customerName;
                private String customerAddress;
                private String customerNumber;
                private String periodT;
                private String periodF;
                private double presentR;
                private double previousR;
                private double previousB;
                private double dueTotal;
                private static ArrayList<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
            
            public billing(int id,String bc,String bd,String customerName,String customerAddress,String customerNumber,String periodT,String periodF,double presentR,double previousR,double previousB,double dueTotal){
                this.id = id;
                this.bc = bc;
                this.bd = bd;
                this.customerName = customerName;
                this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
                this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
                this.periodT = periodT;
                this.periodF = periodF;
                this.presentR = presentR;
                this.previousR = previousR;
                this.previousB = previousB;
                this.dueTotal = dueTotal;
                }
        
            public int getId(){
                return id;
            }
            public String getBc(){
                return bc;
            }
            public String getBd(){
                return bd;
            }
            public String getCustomerName(){
                return customerName;
            }
            public String getCustomerAddress(){
                return customerAddress;
            }
            public String getCustomerNumber(){
                return customerNumber;
            }
            public String getPeriodT(){
                return periodT;
            }
            public String getPeriodF(){
                return periodF;
            }
            public double getPresentR(){
                return presentR;
            }
            public double getPreviousR(){
                return previousR;
            }
            public double getPreviousB(){
                return previousB;
            }
            public double getDue(){
                return dueTotal;
            }
                public static void main(String[] args){
                
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
                Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
                int user_choice;
                int x = 0;
                    
                do{
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("1) New Billing");
                        System.out.println("2) Add Existing Billing");
                        System.out.println("3) View Billing Account ID");
                        System.out.println("4) View By Date");
                        System.out.println("5) Update Existing Billing");
                        System.out.println("6) Delete Billing Account");
                        System.out.println("7) Display All Account");
                        System.out.println("8) Exit");
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.print("Enter choice [1-8]: ");
                        user_choice = scanner.nextInt();
        
                        switch (user_choice){
        
                            case 1: 
                            int min = 1000;
                            int max = 9999;
                            int randomStr = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                            int id = randomStr;
                            System.out.println("Your Account Number is : " + id);
                            System.out.print("Enter Billing Code: ");
                            String bc = scanner.next();
                            System.out.print("Enter Billing Date(dd/mm/yyyy): ");
                            String bd = scanner.next();
                            System.out.print("Enter Customer Name: ");
                            String customerName = kb.nextLine();
                            System.out.print("Enter Customer Address: ");
                            String customerAddress = kb.nextLine();
                            System.out.print("Enter Customer Number: ");
                            String customerNumber = scanner.next();
                            System.out.print("Enter Period To: ");
                            String periodT = scanner.next();
                            System.out.print("Enter Period From: ");
                            String periodF = scanner.next();
                            System.out.print("Enter Present Reading: ");
                            double presentR = scanner.nextDouble();
                            System.out.print("Enter Previous Reading: ");
                            double previousR = scanner.nextDouble();                      
                            System.out.print("Enter Previous Balance: ");
                            double previousB = scanner.nextDouble();
                            double dueTotal = getTotalDue(presentR,previousR,previousB);
                            Account user = new Account(id,bc,bd,customerName,customerAddress,customerNumber,periodT,periodF,presentR,previousR,previousB,dueTotal);
                            accountList.add(user);
                            break;
        
                            case 2:
        
        
                            case 3:
                            System.out.print("Enter Account Number: ");
                                 int a = scanner.nextInt(); 
                                 for(int i = 0; i<accountList.size();i++){
                                    if(a == accountList.get(i).getId()){
                                System.out.println("Account ID: " + accountList.get(i).getId());
                                System.out.println("Customer Name: " +accountList.get(i).getCustomerName());
                                System.out.println("Customer Address: " + accountList.get(i).getCustomerAddress());
                                System.out.print("Customer Number: " + accountList.get(i).getCustomerNumber());
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("\nBilling Code\t\tBilling Date\t\tAmount Due");
                                 for(int i = 0; i<accountList.size();i++){
                                     if(a == accountList.get(i).getId())
                                    {
                                     System.out.println(accountList.get(i).getBc()+"\t\t\t"+accountList.get(i).getBd()+"\t\t\t"+accountList.get(i).getDue());
                                   }
                                }
                                break;
                            case 4:
                            
                            case 5:
                              System.out.print("Enter Account Number: ");
                               a = scanner.nextInt(); 
                              for(int i = 0; i<accountList.size();i++){
                              if(a == accountList.get(i).getId())
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Your Account Number is : " + accountList.get(i).getId());  
                                        System.out.print("Enter Billing Code: ");
                                        String bCode = scanner.next(); 
                                        String c = accountList.get(i).getBc(); //this is the part in which i am having a hard time to fix, ive used the set but still i cannot change the element inside.
                                        int index = accountList.indexOf(c);
                                        accountList.set(index, bCode);
                                         
        
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            break;
                            
                            case 6: 
                            System.out.print("Enter Account Number: ");
                            a = scanner.nextInt(); 
                            System.out.print("Enter Billing Code: ");
                            String b = scanner.next();
                            for(int i = 0; i<accountList.size();i++){
                                if(a == accountList.get(i).getId()){
                                          if(b.equals(accountList.get(i).getBc())){
                                            accountList.remove(i);
                                            System.out.print("\nAccount Removed\n");
        
                                          }else{
                                            System.out.print("Invalid Billing Code\n");
                                          }
                                                   
                                }else if(a != accountList.get(i).getId()){
                                        System.out.print("Invalid Account Number or Number not in the database.\n");
                                }else{
                                    System.out.print("Try Again\n");
                                }
                            }
                      
                            break;
                            
                            case 7:
                            System.out.println("Account ID\t\tBilling Code\t\tAccount Name\t\tTotal Due\t\tPresent R\t\tPrevious R");   
                            Collections.sort(accountList,Collections.reverseOrder());
                            for(int i=0; i<accountList.size();i++){
                                System.out.println(accountList.get(i).getId() + "\t\t\t"+accountList.get(i).getBc()+ "\t\t\t"+accountList.get(i).getCustomerName()+ "\t\t\t"+accountList.get(i).getDue()+"\t\t\t"+accountList.get(i).getPresentR()+ "\t\t\t"+accountList.get(i).getPreviousR());
                            }
                            break;                            
                        }
                             
        
            }while(user_choice!=8);
          }
```

I'm new to programming in Java and I'm still learning towards it. I'm making my **billing system** which calcualtes the payment. My problem for this is how can I change or update the value which is already in the arraylist, I've tried the `set()` but I cannot make it work. using arraylist is a big jump for me and I haven't yet got a hang of it. I've watched youtube vids but they seem to show non user input arry lists

```
Any help?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhF33.png
```

Comment: can you only share the code snippet where you have tried to update a value in the arraylist?

Comment: i have attached already the snippet of the part

Comment: The comment by @aatwork  is pointing out that you posted way **too much code**. When posting a Question on Stack Overflow, you are expected to strip down your code and prose to the bare minimum needed to show your specific technical issue. We do not want to read your entire app's codebase.

Comment: `accountList.get(i).setBc(bCode);` or `accountList.get(i).getBc() = bCode;` maybe?

Comment: @BasilBourque okay, im sorry for posting too much of the code

Comment: Because the problem is that you try to set the list item to be a String (billing code) instead of an Account object.

Comment: @TamasG. ill try that one

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
System.out.println("Your Account Number is : " + accountList.get(i).getId());  
System.out.print("Enter Billing Code: ");
String bCode = scanner.next(); 
String c = accountList.get(i).getBc(); //this is the part in which i am having a hard time to fix, ive used the set but still i cannot change the element inside.
int index = accountList.indexOf(c);
accountList.set(index, bCode);
```

If you want to update billing code in an account then get the account object and update the user entered bCode on the object. Also, you don't have to put the account back in the list:

```
System.out.println("Your Account Number is : " + accountList.get(i).getId());  
System.out.print("Enter Billing Code: ");
String bCode = scanner.next(); 
Account existing = accountList.get(i);
//create new account with same data except bCode
Account updated = new Account(existing.getId(),bCode, existing.getBd(),/*do same for rest of the fields */);
int index = accountList.indexOf(existing);
accountList.set(index, updated);
```

Comment: but what if its a user inputed value? how do I do that?

Comment: You are updating account object here. So set the user entered bCode to the account object and not in the list. I've updated the answer.

Comment: im having a hard time understanding about objects, so i need to create Account c for me to be able to store the inputted values?

Comment: becasue I dont have the setBillingCode in my code so do I need to add this one unto a public setBillingCode?

Comment: Look into Account.java file. And find the getter method which sets billing code to the account and use that method. Share Account class in your opening post.

Comment: ill update my post, as ive looked at my code i do have public String getBc(){
        return bc;
    }

Comment: i dont really have a setter ohhh, i just have the get not set

Comment: I think Account is a data object doesn't have setters. So you 'll have to create a new account with same data except new bCode. I've updated the answer.

Comment: ive made it work, so i used Account instead of using my billing class *facepalm

Comment: Actually you shouldn't be writing this in Account as well as Billing classes. These are data objects. You should create a separate class for business logic like  AccountManager and put the `main` method in there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.
First Option is Loop the list and reach the object you want to change, update its attributes. Since the object is accessed by reference, whatever values you will change it will effect.
Second option is remove the object at that index, create a new object and insert at that position.

```
public void testArrayList ()
{
    
    class MyData
    {
        String Id = "";
        String Name = "";
        
        public MyData () {}
        public MyData (String id, String name) {
            Id= id;
            Name = name;
        }   
        public String toString ()
        {
            return " Id=" + Id + " Name=" + Name; 
        }
    }
    
    ArrayList myDList = new ArrayList ();
    myDList.add(new MyData("1", "John"));
    myDList.add(new MyData("2", "Mike"));
    myDList.add(new MyData("3", "Tom"));
    System.err.println ("Org List                         " + myDList);
    
    MyData tmp = (MyData) myDList.get(1);
    tmp.Id = "22";
    tmp.Name = tmp.Name + " Changed";
    
    System.err.println ("Mod List (Observe second Object ) " + myDList);
}
```

Comment: i understand how it works but, its a bit different if its a user input when I try that

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value in ArrayList to be an object of type Account.

1.You need to get an object of type Account and use settter method to update bcode

2. Set that Account object back to ArrayList

Comment: is it possible to get the same name and acct number after i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Code TL:DR. Do you have a set method in your `Account` class?

```
//set method example
public void setBc(String newBc){ //can also use other data types as parameters
  this.bc = newBc;
}
```

If so you can just

```
accountList.get(i).setBc("This New BCODE"); //The parameter can also be a variable of string type
```

Comment: I dont have the set method yet, i havent even think to put one. i do have get in my code

Comment: If you want to change the value inside an arraylist of object then I think you should [link](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp). Getters and setters are very useful in Object Oriented programming and it can also be used in arraylist of objects. For me its the most logical way to change the values but if you don't want to use it then I'm sorry I can't help you.

Comment: its already a great help. I think i didnt create a public class Account on this one, in vscode it shows Account.class but I cannot even edit that

Answer (score 0):

*You have to change this part in Your program*

```
…
Billing billing = accountList.get(i);  
//String c = billing.getBc();   // this is the part in which I am having a hard time to fix, I've used
                                // the set but still I cannot change the element inside.
billing.setBc( yourNewBc );
//int index = accountList.indexOf(c);
//accountList.set(index, billing);
…
```

class names are capitalized in Java

Answer (score 0):

Here in this example we have iterated over the list and modified the values of the object.
Please make a setter to the values you want to modify and follow something like this.

```
    public class Arr {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Person> array = new ArrayList();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true){
            System.out.println("1.add 2. modify 3.view list ; anything else to to quit");
            int choice = sc.nextInt();
            if (choice==1){
                System.out.println("Enter ID then salary");
                int id = sc.nextInt();
                int salary = sc.nextInt();
                Person p = new Person(id,salary);
                array.add(p);
                System.out.println("Done");
            }
            else if (choice==2){
                System.out.println("Enter ID");
                int id = sc.nextInt();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
                    Person p = array.get(i);
                    if (p.getId()==id){
                        System.out.println("value exits. Enter salary to be modified:");
                        int salary = sc.nextInt();
                        p.setSalary(salary);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Done");
            }
            else if (choice==3){
                for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
                    System.out.print(" " + array.get(i).getId() + " " + array.get(i).getSalary());
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
   }

    public class Person {
        int id;
        int salary;
    
        public Person(int id, int salary) {
            this.id = id;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public int getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }
    
        public void setSalary(int salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    }
```